# Define the Output Name in a Function

Tags: r, function

I would like to manually define the name of the object/output of a function.  A very simple example of what I have is:

```
 x <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 value = c(50, 20, 100))

 statistics <- function(data, name){
          total <- data %>% mutate(New = value +50)
          assign(paste0(name), data)
 }
 statistics(x, "NewName")
```

I would like to run this function and define what data to use and the name of the output.  The idea is to create a uniquely named output for each dataset used.

Thanks!

Comment: Your input argument is `data` while you are using `x` inside.  May be change it to `data %>% mutate`.. and `assign(name, data)` Also, you may need the `envir` for `assign`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just assign the data with the `<-` instead of using `assign()` in the function call. Or you can use assign but you have to specify the envir you would like the object to be assigned too. If it is left blank it will go to the functions environment.
A word of caution on using `assign()` in the function is that is will overwrite other objects in the global env if they have the same name. So be careful with your object names.

```
x <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C"),
                value = c(50, 20, 100))

statistics <- function(data){
  data %>% mutate(New = value +50)
}
Newname <- statistics(x)


statistics2 <- function(data, name){
  total <- data %>% mutate(New = value +50)
  assign(paste0(name), total, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
statistics2(x, "NewName2")
```

A slight aside in your code in your `assign()` it should say total not data.